# How to use the same getView / onBindView code outside of an adapter without repeating it

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter, android-recyclerview

I'd like to know how one might re-use some code more efficiently to display a view that would adapt to a getView()[BaseAdapter], onBindView() [RecyclerView] or a onCreateView() [Fragment] to populate a view?

> Custom RecyclerView adapter which populates a whole list of cardViews

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    MyThing thing = things.get(i);


    /*    Repeatable Code    */

    if (thing.getIcon() == 0) {
        viewHolder.thingIcon.setImageResource(0);
    } else {
        viewHolder.thingIcon.setImageResource(ThingIconSet
                .getIconResId(thing.getIcon()));
    }
etc..etc..etc
```

Now I also want to populate a single cardView outside of this adapter in exactly the same way, without maintaining two copies of this layout, what would you suggest I do?

> SingleItemFragment displaying a **single** item from the adapter or anywhere else

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflating the root view
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_cardview_layout,
            container, false);

    /*    Repeated Code    */

    if (thing.getIcon() == 0) {
        viewHolder.thingIcon.setImageResource(0);
    } else {
        viewHolder.thingIcon.setImageResource(ThingIconSet
                .getIconResId(thing.getIcon()));
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem in a [library](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter) I wrote. The solution was to decouple the view creation, and the view binding from the `Adapter` and have it in a single class per view / element / RecyclerView-item.

So I have implemented a Generic [adapter](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/fastadapter/FastAdapter.java) which takes any class implementing an `interface` (I called it [IItem](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/fastadapter/IItem.java)). This interface defines the methods which are required to create the `View` for the `RecyclerView` define the type and handle everyting. Basically the following are the most important:

```
int getType();
int getLayoutRes();
View generateView(Context ctx);
View generateView(Context ctx, ViewGroup parent);
VH getViewHolder(ViewGroup parent);
void bindView(VH holder);
```

The adapter is able to take any implementations of the item, and visualize them. The great thing about the `item` is that you can even use those items without a `RecyclerView` via the `generateView` methods.

To make it more flexible and easier to implement I added an [AbstractItem](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/fastadapter/items/AbstractItem.java)

You can see the whole implementation here: https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter
Beside the `item` concept it also provides many features most commonly needed in projects with `RecyclerView`s. Most things are very generic to allow the highest possible flexibility.

The implementation should give you a rough idea of how to implement your requirement (or you can use the library). 
You will need:
- A interface for your "item"s
- An adapter able to handle those "item"s
- An "item"-implementation which provides the methods needed for the `RecyclerView` `Adapter`